# Check the username before registering in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, user-registration

I created script for checking username before registering, but it does not work. It returns mistake.
It is script in functions.php:

```
function check_user_login_init(){

    /* Подключаем скрипт для проверки */
    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    /* Локализуем параметры скрипта */
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_check_login_object', array( 
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'loadingmessage' => __('Verified data, wait a second...')
    ));

    // Разрешаем запускать функцию check_user_login() пользователям без привелегий
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_login', 'check_user_login' );    
  }

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('init', 'check_user_login_init');
    }

    function check_user_login(){

        // Первым делом проверяем параметр безопасности
        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

        // Получаем данные из поля #user_login формы и проверяем их
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

        $sanitized_user_name = sanitize_user( $username, 1 );
        if ( username_exists( $sanitized_user_name )) {
                 echo json_encode(array('avaliblename'=>false, 'message'=>__('Choose another name!')));
            } else {
                 echo json_encode(array('avaliblename'=>false, 'message'=>__('OK!')));
            }

        die();
        exit;
    }
```

And here is JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.register_box #registration #user_login').on('keyup', function(e){

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.register_box .status_registration').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
                },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: ajax_check_login_object.ajaxurl,
                cache: false,
                data: { 
                    'action': 'check_user_login', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_checkuserlogin
                    'username': $('.register_box #user_login').val()       
                },
                dataFilter: function(){
                    $('.register_box .status_registration').html('Data processed...');
                },
                error:  function(){

                    $('.register_box .status_registration').html('Something wrong...');

                    },
                success: function(data){


                        $('.register_box .status_registration').html(data.message);
                }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When I try inputting the user name in google chrome it returns the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null

Could you help with this?

Comment: On a side note, use either `die` or `exit`, not both. The second one is never reached.

Comment: I deleted exit, but result not changhed...

Comment: I didn't tell you it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a JavaScript error due to `data.message` not being set. Check in Network tab of your developer toolbar to check what's coming back from the server.

Side-note: it also wouldn't hurt to [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on the server-side to get an idea from the logs of what's going on. Here's how I do it in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); // Turn forced display OFF
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',     true);  // Turn logging to wp-content/debug.log ON
```

And then executing the following line anywhere will push it to `wp-content/debug.log` (which you can monitor):

```
error_log('started processing with array:');
error_log(print_r($array, true));
```

Finally, get rid of `die();` and keep the `exit;` statement.